# Standard pricebook and its relationship with custom pricebooks

Tags: administration, pricebook

We have a standard pricebook and couple of custom ones. The custom pricebooks were recently added. With the new custom pricebooks uploaded and the UseStandardPrice is set to false for the custom pricebook entries as well as standard pricebook enteries.

Does this mean that we would not be able to use the standard pricebook at all? If there is a need to use the prices set in standard pricebook should i create a new pricebook??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, you'll still be able to use the Standard Pricebook.  If you insert a pricebookEntry into a custom pricebook with the useStandardPrice set to True it just inherits the standard pricebook entry's price.  The benefit is that you don't have to set the same price in multiple places.  As for setting the flag on a pricebook entry for the standard pricebook I believe you're require to have useStandardPrice be false.